# Безопасное извлечение USB-flash после работы с файлами в С#

Tags: c#, файлы, usb

В приложении на С# работаю с файлом на USB-flash c помощью потоков FileStream (открываю файл, пишу, закрываю). После этого не удается безопасно извлечь USB-flash. После закрытия приложения USB-flash безопасно извлекается. Как безопасно извлечь USB-flash до закрытия приложения (это важно!!!)?

Код

```
FileStream str_usb = null;
string sPath = "K:\\";
string  name = "qwe.txt"; 
str_usb = new FileStream(sPath + name, FileMode.Create);
int size = 1000;
byte[] buffer;
Random rnd = new Random();
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
    for (int y = 0; y < 1048576; y++)
         buffer [y] = (byte)rnd.Next(0, 255);
    str_usb.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

 str_usb.Close();
 str_usb.Dispose();
```

Добавляю код, который коммпилируется

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {

        public static void write_usb()
        {
            FileStream str_usb = null;
            string sPath = "K:\\";
            string  name = "qwe.txt"; 
            str_usb = new  FileStream (sPath + name, FileMode.Create);
            int size = 1000;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576]; 
            Random rnd = new Random();
               for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
               {
                for (int y = 0; y < 1048576; y++)
                     buffer [y] = (byte)rnd.Next(0, 255);
                str_usb.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
               }

             str_usb.Close();
             str_usb.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Используете `Dispose() / using` ?

Comment: Пробовала Dispose(). Не помогает.

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос.

Comment: Приведённый код даже не скомпилируется: Use of unassigned local variable 'buffer'. Могу предположить, что в вашем реальном коде (который запускается) есть какие-то ошибки и в результате выбрасываются исключения до вызова `Dispose`. Поэтому остаются занятыми неуправляемые ресурсы ниже уровня `FileStream`. Оберните весь ваш код в операторы `using`.

Comment: Отдельно все работает!!!  Причина не в этом коде. Спасибо за замечание о неработающем коде. Вопрос снимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Набросал в соответствии с вашим кодом такой пример консольного приложения:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sPath = @"G:\";
            string name = "123.txt";
            string gPath=Path.Combine(sPath, name);
            if (!File.Exists(gPath))
            {
                File.Create(gPath);
            }
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(gPath))
            {
                int size = 1000;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
                Random rnd = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < 1048576; y++)
                        buffer[y] = (byte)rnd.Next(0, 255);
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

На флешке создается файл размером чуть больше гига(не знаю зачем вы для теста это делали). Флешка успешно извлекается, если вы конечно не откроете с нее этот файл и не попробуете извлечь её.